# What is the best practice for handling Try Catch when writing automated testing?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I'm currently writing test automation for a web based application for my company. I am utilising C#, Visual Studio test suite, and Selenium to perform testing.

Today I asked the question to my colleague of 'Is there any time where there is too many Try Catch blocks in code?'. His reply was to not work as I am at the minute (see example 1), but to just get the lower level try-catch to throw to the upper level try-catch so that the exception can be written there and the test failed (see example 2).

Example 1:

TestCase.cs

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLogin()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(FW_Shared.Perform_Login(FW_Shared.OrgCode, FW_Shared.Username, FW_Shared.Password));
    Console.WriteLine(@"Login Successful");    
}
```

FW_Shared.cs

```
public static class FW_Shared
{
    public static string OrgCode = "Test123";
    public static string Username = "Tester";
    public static string Password = "Password";

    public static void Perform_Login(string OrgCode, string Username, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            Driver.Url = "http://test.app.com/";
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("org_code")).SendKeys(OrgCode);
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(Username);
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(Password);
            Driver.FindElemenet(By.Id("btnsubmit)).Click();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(@"Error occurred logging on: " + ex.ToString());
             return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example 2

TestCase.cs

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLogin()
{
    try
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(FW_Shared.Perform_Login(FW_Shared.OrgCode, FW_Shared.Username, FW_Shared.Password));
        Console.WriteLine(@"Login Successful");  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"Exception caught, test failed: " + ex.ToString());
        Assert.Fail();
    }  
}
```

FW_Shared.cs

```
public static class FW_Shared
{
    public static string OrgCode = "Test123";
    public static string Username = "Tester";
    public static string Password = "Password";

    public static void Perform_Login(string OrgCode, string Username, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            Driver.Url = "http://test.app.com/";
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("org_code")).SendKeys(OrgCode);
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(Username);
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(Password);
            Driver.FindElemenet(By.Id("btnsubmit)).Click();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             throw;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I know that throwing the Exception to be caught is generally useless in typical coding as you want to handle specific exceptions that are returned, but I want to be able to catch any general web page or element issues so the test can fail on a general issue with the web application. For instance:

- If the web page returns 503 or 404 issues
- If an element is not present on the current web page
- If an elements name has changed.

There is points in testing other, more complicated parts of the application that I handle unaccessible parts/elements with true/false bool returns and assert that, but since I am referencing multiple function across different classes would sticking with what I have be best, moving to top-level catching of all lower exceptions, or should I be doing something else?

Comment: The best practice would be to not use `try/catch`. Catching the exception will make it harder to track down the origin of the issue. If you want a customized message, then use the appropriate assert method, and if you want to know exactly which feature failed, then use an explicit name for the test method: `ShouldLoginSuccessfully`.

Comment: We have validation for specific parts such  as what page we expect Selenium to be on, etc. I'm just wondering the best way for general exception catching and how to process that in terms of a failed test.

Answer (score 0):

I normally like to create a test helper method in its own class called "TestRunner.cs" which has a method in I use for all the tests which might throw an exception and I want to test the results of e.g.

```
public static Exception RunCodeThatMayThrowException(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action.Invoke();
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

I can then just use the method like:

```
// Act
var actualException = TestRunner.RunCodeThatMayThrowExeption(() => {//some code});

// Assert
//Do some asserts
```

Comment: So would you use your test helper to call an action such as going to a certain URL or trying to set an new instance of an object? If so, would you then have to check if "var actualException" was empty or not?

Comment: In situations you actually expect an exception to be thrown. When this is the case you can use the method "RunCodeThatMayThrowException" as an easy way to prove that exception has been thrown, is the right type of exception and contains the message you want. I tend to let exceptions bubble up through the layers and not catch them unless it is in a global place like the global.asax on error event handler

Answer (score 0):

Your original **Perform_Login** method states no return parameter (‘void’) and always returns ‘true’ (unless there’s a crash) – these both hint that the method needs some re-factoring.

I would re-factor as follows, which isolates the calling code from the exception, makes the caller agnostic to any errors in the called method, and avoids a series of try-catches passing up the call stack (if your test had a try-catch in it then the production code that calls the method may well require the same):

```
Public Static Class FW_Shared
{
    public static string OrgCode = "Test123";
    public static string Username = "Tester";
    public static string Password = "Password";

    public static bool Perform_Login(string OrgCode, string Username, string Password)
    {
        Try
        {
            Driver.Url = "http://test.app.com/";
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("org_code")).SendKeys(OrgCode);
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(Username);
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(Password);
            Driver.FindElemenet(By.Id("btnsubmit)).Click();
        }
        Catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(@"Error occurred logging on: " + ex.ToString());
             return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
Public Void TestLoginSuccess()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(FW_Shared.Perform_Login(FW_Shared.OrgCode, FW_Shared.Username, FW_Shared.Password));
    Console.WriteLine(@"Login Successful");    
}


[TestMethod]
Public Void TestLoginFailure()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(FW_Shared.Perform_Login(FW_Shared.OrgCode, “foo”, “bar”));
    Console.WriteLine(@"Login Failed");    
}
```

Comment: The example given is just that, an example. The actual login performance is to be utilised for initialising each test since selenium needs to be on the page in question before performing actions (like adding documents to our web application). We have a data driven test that goes through each login and validates those. I'm in need of knowing the best practice for TryCatch and how to action this, but I appreciate the answer.

Comment: No probs - not sure if it helps, and you may already be aware of this, but you can set your test to expect an exception of a particular type. This does vary from framework to framework, but either MSTest or Nunit has (or had at least) a method annotation which was something like, for example, '[ExpectedException(typeOf(NotImplementedException))]'. This may or may not be useful in your scenario (sorry about the "you're" earlier which I've now corrected :-) ).

Comment: If that can catch un-implemented exceptions that may be what I need to pull through. I'll have a look at this, thanks.